# Frequency of error type 1 in R

Tags: r, statistics, frequency

I need help to find the frequency of error type I in R.
I need to estimate a statistic model with OLS and using the MonteCarlo (1000000 times) and find out  the frequency of error type I ( reject the null hypotesis) with the level of confidence of 0.95.

Here is my code:

```
#estimating  B^ 

Estima_Beta <- function(vetor_y,matriz_x){
  vetor <- solve(crossprod(matriz_x)) %*% t(matriz_x) %*% vetor_y
  return(as.vector(vetor))
}


Estima_s2 <- function(vetor_y,matriz_x){

  a <- vetor_y - matriz_x%*%Estima_Beta(vetor_y,matriz_x)
  s2 <- crossprod(a)/(Num_obs-Num_var)
  return(s2[1,1])   
}

#estimating variance

Estima_variancia <- function(vetor_y,matriz_x){
  var_betas <- c()
  matriz <- Estima_s2(vetor_y,matriz_x)*solve(crossprod(matriz_x))
  for (i in c(1:Num_var)){
   var_betas[i] <- matriz[i,i]
   }
  return(matriz)
}

#estimating t statistic

Estima_t <- function(vetor_y,matriz_x){
matriz_variancia   <- Estima_variancia(vetor_y, matriz_x)
vetor_betas        <- Estima_Beta(vetor_y, matriz_x)
desvio_betas       <- c()
estat_t            <- c()
for (i in c(1:Num_var)){
 estat_t[i]  <- vetor_betas[i]/(matriz_variancia[i,i]^(0.5))
  }
  return(estat_t)
}



Beta1 <- 0.131
Beta2 <- 0.909
Betasjuntos <- c(Beta1,Beta2)
Num_obs <- 27
Num_var <- 2


c   <- 2
Phi <- 0.6

# vector N 

N   <- rnorm(Num_obs,0,1)

#generating x0

xo <-  rnorm(1,c/(1-Phi),(1/(1-Phi^2))^(0.5))

#generating x

vetor_x_temp <- c(xo)

for (i in c(1:Num_obs)){
  vetor_x_temp[i+1] <- c + Phi*vetor_x_temp[i] + N[i]
}

vetor_x <- vetor_x_temp[2:length(vetor_x_temp)]

#generating E

E   <- rnorm(Num_obs,0,1)


   #doing 1 million times

    matriz_beta <- matrix(,1000000,Num_var)
    matriz_t    <- matriz_beta


   for (j in (1:1000000)){
  E        <- rnorm(Num_obs,0,1)
 vetor_y  <- c()

  for (i in c (1:Num_obs)){
   vetor_y[i] <- Beta1 + Beta2*vetor_x[i] + E[i]
   }

  m_X <- matrix(1,Num_obs,Num_var)
  m_X[,2] <- vetor_x

  matriz_beta[j,]  <- Estima_Beta(vetor_y, m_X)
  matriz_t[j,]     <- Estima_t(vetor_y, m_X)

}

#frequency
    t.test(vetor_betas,Betasjuntos,"two.sided",conf.level=0.95)
    data.frame(table(cut(vetor_betas,seq(-2.168931,2.622706))))

#the data.frame part isnt right, how can i correct that?
```

Comment: So what is your question exactly?

Comment: how to calculate the frequency of errors type 1? is there any functions that i can use to find frequency?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very hard to understand so that I'll just leave an example using a simple test of mean.

Type I error - A type I error is the incorrect rejection of a true null hypothesis.

Below the true mean is 1 so that, if a test rejects the null hypothesis of mean = 1, type I error is made - in the code, the test is made by specifying `mu = 1`.

Then the frequency is simply (# error / # simulation), which is 0.1 in this toy example. (Don't be confused that, for modelling, the purpose is usually to reject the null so that the smaller p-value, the better. However, in this case, if the sample rejects the null, it'll be making an error as the theoretical mean is known to be 1 and it shouldn't be rejected ideally.)

By the way, would you really need 1M simulation for such a simple example?

```
set.seed(1237)
mu <- 1
sd <- 2
trial <- 10
sim <- sapply(1:trial, function(x) {
  rnd <- rnorm(100, mu, sd)
  p <- t.test(rnd, mu = mu,
              alternative = "two.sided", conf.level = 0.95)$p.value
  c(mean = mean(rnd), pvalue=p)
})
sim
            [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]       [,6]      [,7]      [,8]     [,9]      [,10]
mean   1.0629732 1.0487337 1.0812699 0.7263932 0.7369841 1.29916463 1.3225481 1.0276262 1.010063 0.60022291
pvalue 0.7638974 0.8006087 0.6927136 0.1671541 0.1855383 0.08513691 0.1326339 0.8996161 0.959935 0.04788333
sum(sim[2,] < 0.05)/ncol(sim)
0.1
```